# nGinx rewrite if previous rewrite did not find any file

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a apache rewrite for a site that runs on wordpress like this:

```
RewriteRule ^((images|stylesheets|scripts)/.+)$ /assets/$1 [NC,L]
```

I converted to nGinx which seems like this:

`rewrite /((images|stylesheets|scripts)/.+)$ /assets/$1 break;`

There is no problem with this directive, it runs fine and does it's job.
The problem now is with wordpress files.
If I try opening **/wp-content/themes/fluidblog/library/media/images/banner.png** it will come as 404. Can you help me figure out how to make nginx understand that I want the rewrite only for the first subdirectory so it's not searching within all path?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to be a empty poster, but figured it out my self!
        location /images { rewrite /images/(.*)$ /assets/images/$1; }
        location /stylesheets { rewrite /stylesheets/(.*)$ /assets/stylesheets/$1; }
        location /scripts { rewrite /scripts/(.*)$ /assets/scripts/$1; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you seem to have figured it out, but i would like to suggest a simpler answer, might need some fixing but you'll get the idea,
**Note**: I haven't tested those.

```
location ~ /(?:images|stylsheets|scripts)
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /assets/$1;
}
```

or maybe

```
location ~ /(?:images|stylesheets|scripts)
    rewrite ^ /assets$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Hi, yeah this makes better sense and keeps things dynamic. Thanks in reply.